# Having trouble adding JScrollBar/JScrollPane to this JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

Ok, so here's a snippet of my code containing the problem:

```
private JTextField userText;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;
private JTextPane images;
private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(images); 

public Server(){
   super(name+" - IM Server");
  images = new JTextPane();
  images.setContentType( "text/html" );
  HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)images.getDocument();
  userText = new JTextField();
  userText.setEditable(false);
  userText.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
           sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
           userText.setText("");
        }
     }
  );
  add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(jsp);
  add(images, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  images.setEditable(false);
  try {
    doc.insertString(0, "This is where images and text will show up.\nTo send an image, do\n*image*LOCATION OF IMAGE\n with NO SPACES or EXTRA TEXT.", null );
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  setSize(700,400);
  setVisible(true);
  ImageIcon logo = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("CHAT.png"));
  setIconImage(logo.getImage());
}
```

and when I use it, there's no scrollbar on my JTextPane?! I have tried moving add(jsp); above and below where it is, and moving it below add(images, BorderLayout.NORTH); greys it out?! So what I want to know is how to add this JScrollPane to my JTextPane to give it a scrollbar. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Bascially, you actually never add a valid component to the `JScrollPane`...

```
private JTextPane images;
private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(images);
```

When this executes, `images` is `null`, so basically, you are calling `new JScrollPane(null);`

Then, you basically add `images` over the top of (replacing) `jsp` on the frame...

```
add(jsp);
add(images, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The default position is `BorderLayout.CENTER` and border layout can only support a single component in any of it's 5 available positions...

Instead, try something like...

```
public Server(){
    super(name+" - IM Server");
    images = new JTextPane();
    images.setContentType( "text/html" );
    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)images.getDocument();
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
           sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
           userText.setText("");
        }
     }
    );
    add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jsp.setViewportView(images);
    add(jsp);
    //add(images, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    images.setEditable(false);
    try {
        doc.insertString(0, "This is where images and text will show up.\nTo send an image, do\n*image*LOCATION OF IMAGE\n with NO SPACES or EXTRA TEXT.", null );
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setSize(700,400);
    setVisible(true);
    ImageIcon logo = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("CHAT.png"));
    setIconImage(logo.getImage());
}
```